# Php fatal error on installing composer from project

Tags: php, symfony, redis, composer-php

This is the fatal error message occuring:

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception


  [RuntimeException]                                                           
  An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command:    
  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorEx  
  ception: Warning: Declaration of Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client::ge  
  t() should be compatible with Redis::get($key) in /home/PRIVATE/Prop/ve  
  ndor/snc/redis-bundle/Client/Phpredis/Client.php:1389                        
  Stack trace:                                                                 
  #0 /home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debu  
  g/DebugClassLoader.php(169): Symfony\Component\Debug\ErrorHandler->handleEr  
  ror(2, 'Declaration of ...', '/home/nienormal...', 1389, Array)              
  #1 /home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Debu  
  g/DebugClassLoader.php(169): require_once()                                  
  #2 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Debug\DebugClassLoader->loadClass  
  ('Snc\\RedisBundle...')                                                      
  #3 /home/PRIVATE/Prop/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php(577  
  0): spl_autoload_call('Snc\\RedisBundle...')                                 
  #4 /home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Depe  
  ndencyInjection/Container.php(314): appDevDebugProjectContainer->getSncRedi  
  s_CacheService()                                                             
  #5 /home/PRIVATE/Prop/app/c in /home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/snc/redis-  
  bundle/Client/Phpredis/Client.php on line 1389
```

This project is cloned from git and this error occurs after installation packets from `composer install`.

I want to run project on Ubuntu platform, but I'm totally green in this thema.

Sorry for my bad english but maybe someone will help me with this dark magic.

Comment: Please give us more information on what project did you clone, what command did you run, so we can reproduce the problem and help you with it.

Comment: This is symfony project with many bundles. I use git@git.private... to clone it. After clone in project was composer.json file to install all bundles in it.

On gitlab project was some information about instalation things like npm, bower, composer, grunt, redis git and PHP with: 
- php-mcrypt
- php-intl
- php-pdo-pgsql
- php-redis
Im not sure if i did all things good.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error after upgrating to php-redis 3.1.4RC. It looks like a [BC breaking feature was introduced](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis/issues/1233)

For `ondrej` ubuntu repository

```
cd /tmp
wget https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+build/12376478/+files/php-redis_3.1.2-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i php-redis_3.1.2-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: I can confirm that 3.1.4RC introduced BC breaks. Any suggestion on how to downgrade it? On Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the error you encounter is not link with composer, but with the RedisBundle from your Symfony app.

See this message : 

`Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: Warning: Declaration of Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client::get() should be compatible with Redis::get($key) in /home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/snc/redis-bundle/Client/Phpredis/Client.php:1389`

Apparently you have a `Client` class : in `Snc\RedisBundle\Client\Phpredis\Client.php` which inherit `/home/PRIVATE/Prop/vendor/snc/redis-bundle/Client/Phpredis/Client.php` from Redis.
Since it's inheritance, both methods should have the same signature.

So change your method `Client::get()` -> `Client::get($key)` even if you don't use the `$key` parameter. 
And it should work fine.

Comment: Ok i will test it when i will be at home. Thanks for answer Thibault

Answer (score 0):

You can install phpredis 3.1.2 from the [source](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis#installation). Just clone a repo, switch to tag 3.1.2 and run:

```
phpize
./configure
make && make install
```

Then update path to `redis.so` in extension's ini file. Reload PHP